# IRS Payer/Receiver swap dv01

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap

I was just wondering whether it was possible for long payer swaps to have a negative dv01 and vice versa for a short payer to have a positive dv01? Intuitively by definition of payers and receivers I didnt think this was possible, but I was recently pricing some payers/receivers on Bloomberg and saw that this was in fact possible? Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just posted a screenshot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delta/DV01 is expressed with regards to a downward shift in rates. So in this case for a long payer, a 1bp downward shift would result in a loss of \$40k. For the short payer it'd be the opposite, i.e. a \$30k gain.

The DV01 itself is calculated as the average move in P&L for a 10bp shift up and down (i.e. numerically and not analytically).

Comment: brilliant thank you so much! I just wanted to ask, is this a general convention for the quotation of swap deltas or just specific to bloomberg?

Comment: Think it's specific to Bloomberg but can be explained by how risk is expressed for bonds. E.g. bond duration is usually positive which means if yields decrease by 1%, the bond price appreciates.

Comment: very much appreciated, thank you.